# react cron expression generator for bullmq?

Tags: reactjs, bullmq

we need to generate a corn expression that Bullmq can accept.

I have tried [react-cron-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cron-generator). but it's not accepted by Bullmq.

Corn expression to run a job  *every day 3:15 am*

react-corn-generator : 0 15 03 1/1 * ? * 
Bullmq accepted expression : 0 15 3 * * *

Answer (score 1):

BullMQ uses a different format for cron expressions compared to what you generated with the `react-cron-generator`. BullMQ follows the standard cron format, which consists of five fields (minute, hour, day of the month, month, day of the week). The format you've mentioned for BullMQ is correct:

```
0 15 3 * * *
```

This expression breaks down as follows:

- Minute: 0 (meaning 0 minutes past the hour)
- Hour: 15 (3:15 AM)
- Day of the month: 3 (every day of the month)
- Month: * (every month)
- Day of the week: * (every day of the week)

So, this cron expression will indeed run a job every day at 3:15 AM, which is what you want. You can use this expression directly with BullMQ to schedule your job to run at the desired time.

Comment: is there any plugin to generate that cron expression bullmq ? or can you suggest any workaround to induce that cron expression in react?